# How to solve LaTeX package warning for "everypage"?

Tags: background, package, dependencies, latex, warnings

After updating MiKTeX, Texmaker and all installed packages, I receive an error when compiling the document. The error message is the following:

> Package everypage Warning: Functionality similar to this package has recently been implemented in LaTeX. This package is now in legacy status. Please, don't use it in new documents and packages.

> Package everypage Warning: You appear to be running a version of LaTeX providing the new functionality. Doing the best to deliver the original `everypage` interface on top of it. Strict equivalence is not possible, breakage may occur. If truly needed, Use `everypage-1x` to force the loading of an older code base.

The error is caused by the code `\usepackage[some]{background}`, also without the parameter "some". So the package background has a dependency to the package everypage which causes the error.

The document is compiling, but I would like to resolve the warning. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Here you can find a compilable minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, parskip, 10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[some]{background}%Warning
\definecolor{font}{RGB}{46, 49, 51}

\begin{document}
    \color{font}
    {\Huge Text}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the cause: There was a recent update to LaTeX, documented here:

[LaTeX News Issue 32, October 2020](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews32.pdf)

The updated provided native hook management, including those related to page shipout - something that was provided by [`everypage`](//ctan.org/pkg/everypage). The package maintainer provided [an update to `everypage`](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.3825.1602497744.2548.ctan-ann@ctan.org) stating this:

> Package is now in a legacy status. Functionality similar to that
> provided by this package is directly implemented in LaTeX since its
> 2020 Fall release. On new enough LaTeX formats, `everypage` now merely
> emulates its legacy interface on top of the new LaTeX mechanisms for
> compatibility reasons, while on older formats, it fall backs to its
> own previous code.
>
> Do not use `everypage` in new documents and do not rely on it in new
> packages or classes of yours.

The maintainer of [`background`](//ctan.org/pkg/background) will have to update the package to utilise the new hooks rather than rely on `everypage`. Alternatively, write your own `background`-like macros (whatever that may be).

In the interim you could just suppress the warnings using [`silence`](//ctan.org/pkg/silence):

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[everypage]% Suppress warnings related to package everypage
\usepackage[...]{everypage}
```